# Xcode - How can I call Return parameter in method when all requestAccessToEntityType block is done?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6, objective-c-blocks

I have method that returns for iOS6 whether user allowed access to calendar or no.

```
-(NSString *)CheckCalendarAllowed{

  __block NSString *AllowCalendar;

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted){
        NSLog(@"Event store granted");
        AllowCalendar = @"1";
        
        NSLog(@"AllowCalendar in block = %@",AllowCalendar);
        
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Event store not granted");
        AllowCalendar = @"0";
        
        NSLog(@"AllowCalendar in block = %@",AllowCalendar);
    }
}];


NSLog(@"AllowCalendar before return = %@",AllowCalendar);
return AllowCalendar;
}
```

In console I get this.

> 2012-12-16 20:48:18.418 22052012_xxxx[4346:907] AllowCalendar before
> return = (null)
>
> 2012-12-16 20:48:18.460 22052012_xxxx[4346:110b] Event store granted
>
> 2012-12-16 20:48:18.462 22052012_xxxx[4346:110b] AllowCalendar in
> block = 1

How can I call Return parameter when all requestAccessToEntityType block is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use blocks in this way. There are so many ways to implement this. One way is to try splitting the caller method to two separate methods and do the features as follows,

```
-(void)CheckCalendarAllowed{

  NSString *AllowCalendar;
  EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

  [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted){
        NSLog(@"Event store granted");
        AllowCalendar = @"1";

        NSLog(@"AllowCalendar in block = %@",AllowCalendar);
        [self returnAllowCalendarValue:AllowCalendar];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Event store not granted");
        AllowCalendar = @"0";

        NSLog(@"AllowCalendar in block = %@",AllowCalendar);
        [self returnAllowCalendarValue:AllowCalendar];
    }
  }];
}
```

Then call the method as,

```
[self CheckCalendarAllowed];
```

And implement the features once you have received the above value in method,

```
-(void)returnAllowCalendarValue:(NSString *)allowCalendarString {
  //implement the rest of the operations here
  NSLog(@"AllowCalendar = %@", allowCalendarString);
}
```

On a side note, as per apple coding conventions, variable names and method names should start with lower case. Please use `allowCalendar` and `checkCalendarAllowed` as the names.